# brightness can not be controlled in sony vaio laptop

Tags: brightness, vaio, sony

Brightness is not varying. The screen is seemed to be in maximum brightness. Help me somebody please.

Answer (score 1):

1.Open file `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

2.There will be something like: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash".`

Change it to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

3.Save file

4.Run command

```
sudo update-grub
```

5.Reboot